# Unexpected scrollbar: overflow and scroll, absolute div with :hover

Tags: html, css, scroll, hover, css-position

I'm trying to build a pure-css mouse-over menu, where a `DIV` appears to the right of an item that is hovered. The basic idea is to use an absolute positioned `DIV` that appears on `:hover`

It will look like this (colors for debugging purposes)

**Result**

[image]

**Relevant CSS**

```
.hoverDiv:hover .hoverItem
{
  background-color: green;
}
.hoverDiv:hover .hoverMenu
{
  display:inline-block;  
}
.hoverMenu
{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  left:100%;
  top:0px;
}
```

This works great. However, if there are too many items I would like to have a (vertical) scrollbar. But when I add `overflow-y:scroll`, the hover effect also triggers a horizontal scrollbar.

See https://jsfiddle.net/g2g1zutb/12/ , the red section is 'wrong', the yellow section is OK, but has no scroll.

What would be the best way to solve this? Is it even possible in CSS only?

Comment: here is an idea about a pseudo-solution with only CSS : https://jsfiddle.net/g2g1zutb/25/ ... but for a generic one i think JS is needed

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif, but please note the hover on item 2 is positioned in the wrong place.

Comment: i know :) that's why i said it's a pseudo-solution or i had put it as an answer ;)

Comment: I see, thanks for taking the time though!

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what would improve this question? I'd gladly improve it.

Comment: JS 'solution': https://jsfiddle.net/g2g1zutb/106/